# Initialize entire array with a value in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, gcc, header

I was trying to initialise an entire `int` array and after searching through Stackoverflow, i found that the best way is to use `std::fill_n` from `<algorithm>` or `<vector>` header but including both is giving an error. I think these methods are only possible in C++ or am I doing something wrong?

> How can I initialise an entire array with a value in C without any loops i.e. in a single statement?

I am working on Fedora 14 terminal and compiling it using gcc.

Comment: @Ryan Haining: Why did you replace [C] tag with [C++] tag when the question is clearly about C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reusable universal solution can be built in the following fashion

1. Write a "stable" `memcpy_forward` function (analog of standard `memcpy`) that copies memory regions in forward direction specifically

   ```
   void *memcpy_forward(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
   {
     char *pdst;
     const char *psrc;

     for (pdst = dst, psrc = src; n > 0; --n, ++pdst, ++psrc)
       *pdst = *psrc;

     return dst;
   }
   ```
2. To fill an array like

   ```
   int a[1000];
   ```

   with the same value (say, `42`) first do

   ```
   a[0] = 42;
   ```

   and then do

   ```
   memcpy_forward(a + 1, a, sizeof a - sizeof *a);
   ```

This trick can be used to fill any memory region with repetitive pattern of any size. You start by forming the initial "sample" of the pattern at the beginning of the region and then use `memcpy_forward` to replicate that pattern across the desired region.

Comment: Thanks it is really a new way I learned to copy elements on memory bit level.

Answer (score 5):

If you have your array declaration `int arr[ARRAY_SIZE];`, then you can fill it with an int `VALUE` with the following code (the declaration of `i` needs to be at the beginning of a block).

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
   arr[i] = VALUE;
```

A simple `for` loop will do.

Comment: For loop was the obvious answer. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The most general way is to write a loop to initialize:

```
for (i = 0; i < some_len; ++i) {
    ary[i] = some_val;
}
```

If you just need 0, `memset` or initialization will work.  But I'm guessing you're looking for arbitrary values.  The `memset` call can fill your array with arbitrary patterns of a single byte, which probably isn't what you're after.

Comment: "arbitrary patterns of bytes" sounds wrong. `memset` can set every byte to the same specified value. "arbitrary patterns" makes it sound like it can set different bytes to different values, which I'm sure isn't what you meant.

Comment: It isn't.  I meant that you could have any value from [0,`(2 << CHAR_BIT)`-1] filling the array bytewise, not just 0.

Comment: Quibble: You mean `1 << CHAR_BIT`

Answer (score 1):

[`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) is indeed an algorithm from C++ that you cannot use in C.

Bear in mind that `fill_n` does not initialize the array, it assigns a specified value to each an every element of the array.

To do a similar thing in C, you have to iterate over elements of the array and assign a value to each and every one. For example:

```
// Compile: gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -o test ./test.c

int main()
{
    double array[100];
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]); ++i)
        array[i] = 9.99;
}
```

If your array is a byte string, then using `memset` may be a better choice — developers are familiar with it so the code would be more compact, and it may also be faster. For example:

```
// Compile: gcc -std=c99 -Wall -pedantic -o test ./test.c
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char array[100];
    memset(array, 1, sizeof(array)); // Set every element to 1.
}
```

If you want to initialize instead of doing assignment, then you need to either:

- Use zero-initializer to set each element to 0: `int array[100] = { 0 };`
- Specify each element's value: `int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Comment: This will set every byte to 1, not every element in the array to 1. `int`s are multiple bytes, and so the elements of the array will not be 1.

Comment: Ah, crap, yeah it was silly of me. I mean byte array, not int array. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, those are C++ libraries. You can actually tell just by looking because C standard library headers end with `.h` while C++ standard library headers don't. For example, in C you would use `<stdio.h>` but in C++ you would use `<cstdio>`.

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the conclusion is that there is no pre-defined way to initialise entire array using an expression and that std::fill_n is only possible in C++.

The only way is the `brute force for loop`.

Answer (score 0):

if you need initialize with 0 or ~0, or any byte value, populated into all bytes of your integer, you can use bzero() or memset().